# Confused about canning process time for stock versus stock with meat in it

Tags: canning, broth

I have an all American pressure canner that I use for canning venison, and I wanted to can some stock as well.  I followed the recipe and instructions in the manual, including the part that said “remove bones, cool broth and *pick off the meat, then add meat removed from bones to broth,* process etc”. The process time given was 25 minutes.
Then I was reading everywhere online that broth with meat in it should be processed for the full time of 90 minutes. Does anyone know if the 25 minutes is adequate?  The amount of meat was a couple inches on the bottom of the jar.  I would expect the all American instructions to be accurate but I’m concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Both the [NCHFP](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_05/stock_broth.html) and the [USDA](https://www.nifa.usda.gov/sites/default/files/resource/Canning%20Meat%20Poultry%20and%20Game.pdf) recommend 25 minutes for meat broth, with or without meat in it.  I believe the recommendations you are seeing for 90 minutes is the time for a jar packed with pieces of meat, not for meat in broth.